# grant permission for tables only in Snowflake with dbt

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have this configuration in my dbt_project.yml:

```
models:
  company:
    marts:
      materialized: table
      my_schema:
        +schema: my_schema
        +grants:
          select: [ 'REPORTER' ]
        intermediate:
          materialized: view
```

I want to grant only for tables, but this applies for tables and views (the intermediate entities).

Is there someway to apply this grant only for the tables of my_schema?
Thank you.

[EDIT]

I achieved success with this. I added the roles for all entities and overwrited the views' roles in sequence:

```
my_schema:
  +schema: my_schema
  +grants:
    select: [ 'REPORTER', 'ROLE2' ]
  intermediate:
    materialized: view
    +grants:
      select: [ 'ROLE2' ]
```

But I though whether could exist a more straightforward way for granting only on the tables like this:

```
my_schema:
  +schema: my_schema
  +grants:
    select: [ 'REPORTER' ]
    type: table
  intermediate:
    materialized: view # ROLE2'd not be revoked in views in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a macro and execute it on a post-hook:

```
{# Macro takes in a Relation #}
{% macro setup_table_grants(rel) %}
  {% if rel.is_table %}
    grant select on table {{ rel.name }} to role REPORTER;
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Inside `dbt_project.yml`

```
models:
  company:
    marts:
      materialized: table
      my_schema:
        +schema: my_schema
        post-hook:
          - "{{ setup_table_grants(this) }}"
        intermediate:
          materialized: view
```

Comment: I added in the question the approach I used. I worked fine for me. I think it's leaner. Tks for helping.

Comment: @LucasMendesMotaDaFonseca - Yes, your answer would be the default go to. I had assumed from your question that you were going to have a mix of materializations at different levels of your project, and/or you could have a materialization override at the model config level. If that ends up being the case, your approach won't work. But if your materialization configurations are consistent, your approach is cleaner for sure.